# passing arguments right in app.use (NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to understand why the code 1 works, and why the 2 does not..

app.js:

```
// Routes
var server = require('./routes/server');

app.use('/', server);
```

Route.js:

```
var express     = require('express');
var resource    = require('express-resource');

var server = express();

server.resource('exampleserver', require('../controllers/example'));

module.exports = server;
```

Ok, working good.

When i try pass everything to one file, the server will break:

app.js:

```
    var express     = require('express');
    var resource    = require('express-resource');

    var server = express();


// Routes
app.use('/', resource('exampleserver', require('./controllers/example')));
```

This will appear in the terminal:

```
/Users/marceloalves/Desktop/MVC-Structure/node_modules/express-resource/index.js:63
    if (actions[key]) this.mapDefaultAction(key, actions[key]);
                           ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mapDefaultAction'
    at Resource (/Users/marceloalves/Desktop/MVC-Structure/node_modules/express-resource/index.js:63:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marceloalves/Desktop/MVC-Structure/app.js:40:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Can anyone give me a hand here? haha

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you don't use `server.resource()`, but call `resource()` directly. Try this:

```
app.use('/', server.resource('exampleserver', require('./controllers/example')));
```